# Change base url of Magento 2 without Changing in Magento Database

Tags: magento2, base-url

How to Change base URL of Magento 2 without Changing in Magento Database

For Example:
`magnentoxyz.com` means it will redirect to my Magento frontend
`localhost/` means it will go to phpmyadmin page

Comment: There are multiple methods for that, [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105853/how-to-change-base-url) will help you.

Comment: Can you explain more? What you do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why you want to set baseurl from some other place then DB

But I can tell you from where magento set `base url`

In `vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php` file,

you can find `getBaseUrl()` method

in this method magento set `baseurl`